# How to reopen socket connection?

Tags: java, sockets, connection, client, server

How to reopen socket connection of the client, if sever was stopped then ran again?

P.S. Maybe it is not necessary to view all the code, just look through the "wait" loop in the Client code.

```
Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);

while (true) 
{
    line = keyboard.readLine();
    try 
    {
       out.writeUTF(line);
       out.flush();
       line = in.readUTF();
    } 
    catch (SocketException e) 
    {
       while (socket.isClosed()) 
       {
           System.out.println("no signal");
           try 
           {
                Thread.sleep(200);
           }
           catch (InterruptedException e1) 
           {
                e1.printStackTrace();
           }

           //Here I need some code for reconnection
         }

    }
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: If connection was closed then I would say create new connection same way you always do.

Comment: even after creating new socket it is still Closed ((


**socket = new Socket(socket.getInetAddress(), socket.getPort());**

Comment: `new Socket(socket.getInetAddress(), socket.getPort())` is not "*same way you always do*". See AlexR's answer to see what I meant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If socket closed connection client should get exception on read/write operation. If client wants to re-new the connection, just implement it. You catch block should create new socket exactly as you are doing in the beginning of your code snippet.

Something like the following:

```
while(true) {
    Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);
    try {
        while(true) {
           // read/write operations
        }
    } catch (SocketException e) {
       continue; // this will return you to creation of new socket
    }
}
```